# How do I take an element from the previous row in a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe with asset prices (open, high, low, close, 8 & 21 day moving averages, etc). When back testing I want to take an element from the previous row (for stop loss purposes) but my prices are floats so I cannot use .iloc[] as that only works with integers.
How can I take an element from the row above?

Obviously my code is wrong (line 6) and takes the current close, instead I want the previous 'entry' level from the row above. I cannot use iloc[]? is there an alternative way?

```
def entry1(sp500):
    if sp500['8maUP'] == 1   and sp500['8maUP1'] ==0 :
        x = sp500['close']
        return x  # sp500['close']
    elif sp500['8maUP'] ==1 and sp500['8maUP1'] ==1 :
        x = sp500.iloc[3]                                  #cannot use iloc
        return x 
    else:       
        return '0'
sp500['entry']= sp500.apply(entry1, axis = 1)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
def entry1(sp500):
    if sp500['8maUP'] == 1 and sp500['8maUP1'] == 0:
        x = sp500['close']
        return x
    elif sp500['8maUP'] == 1 and sp500['8maUP1'] == 1:
        x = sp500['entry'].shift(1)  # Access the previous row's 'entry' value
        return x
    else:
        return 0  # Returning an integer instead of a string '0'

# Assuming you have a DataFrame named sp500
sp500['entry'] = sp500.apply(entry1, axis=1)
```

In the modified code, `sp500['entry'].shift(1)` accesses the 'entry' column from the previous row using the `.shift()` method. This way, you can access the previous 'entry' level without using `.iloc[]`. Also, I changed the '0' to an integer 0 to be consistent with numeric values.

**Or you can use this:**

```
x = sp500['close'].lag(1) #use lag() to get previous row close
```

Comment: thanks Mohamad but the numbers are floats so .lag will not work

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'lag'

Comment: You are right, the `lag()` function does not work with floats. However, you can use the `Series.shift()` method instead.